# scanf in while loop not evaluating first block of information

Tags: c

Trying to get `scanf` to iterate and evaluate each section of the string with `isdigit`.  However it seems to be skipping the first 'block' thus offsetting everything.  Recommendations on what I'm doing wrong?

```
int main (void) {
    int icount = 0;
    int c = 0;
    int compare = 0;
    int len = 0;
    char s[256] = "";
    printf("Enter a string:\n\n");
    while (scanf("%s", s) == 1) {
       scanf("%255s", s);
       len = strlen(s);
       printf("the string is %d characters long\n", len);
       while (len > 0) {
          printf("c is on its s[%d] iteration\n", c);
          if (isdigit(s[c])) {
             compare = compare + 1;
          }
          c++;
          len--;
       }
       if (compare == strlen(s)) {
          icount = icount + 1;
       }
       c++;
    }
    printf("\ni count is %d\n", icount);
    return 0;
}
```

When I run it I keep getting data back like this:

```
./a
Enter a string:
17 test 17
the string is 4 characters long
c is on its s[0] iteration
c is on its s[1] iteration
c is on its s[2] iteration
c is on its s[3] iteration
the string is 2 characters long
c is on its s[5] iteration
c is on its s[6] iteration
i count is 0
```

Comment: Why are you `scanf()`ing twice, is it a typo? I mean copy paste issue.

Comment: Remove the `scanf()` just after the `while (scanf(…) == 1) {`?  You're also going to need to reset `c` to 0 somewhere in the loop, I think.

Comment: no wasn't a typo I thought I had to use the first scanf as my condition and the second as what was actually happening within the loop?

Comment: You are skipping the first `scanf()`ed string, so that's why or program has issues, but you could also use a better approach than `while (len > 0)`, something like `for (i = 0 ; s[i] != '\0' ; ++i)`

Comment: also if I reset c to zero within the loop then won't it be looking back at the s[0] portion of the array as opposed to moving onto the next block?

Comment: so you're saying I should remove the second scanf and change the while code to a for with not equal to null.  I'll give it a shot thanks for the time

Comment: awesome you were correct on the second scanf but as far as I can tell incorrect on the resetting of the c value, that would cause it to be evaluating the wrong parts of the array.  Thank you very much though you have been a great help.

Comment: I take it back you were correct on both counts, looks like it reevaluates as if it's at the beginning each time.  Thanks again

Comment: It is curious that your debugging print `printf("c is on its s[%d] iteration\n", c);` doesn't print the value of `s[c]`.  It is certainly the first thing I'd want to do in handling this.  Make sure you see the data that the program got, so you know whether the program is seeing what you thought it should be seeing.  After the `scanf()`, print the string: `printf("Read: <<%s>>\n", s);` for example.

Comment: jon - a good tip, I was mainly concerned with the length of string it was reading, since all my inputs were of varying length I could deduce that it was reading my inputs correctly.  But my main concern wasn't what it was reading but how long it thought they were and if it thought they were an integer or not.  However I have added that for my debugging and it is nice to have in the process thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ended up going with this simple code as my knowledge level is... well... simple
.  thanks for the help with that iteration and second scanf it was about to drive me over the edge!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main (void) {
    int icount = 0;
    int c = 0;
    int compare = 0;
    char s[256] = "";
    printf("Enter a string:\n\n");
    while (scanf("%255s", s) == 1) {
       compare = 0;
       for (c = 0 ; s[c] != '\0' ; c++) {
          if (isdigit(s[c])) {
             compare = compare + 1;
          }
       }
       if (compare == strlen(s)) {
          icount = icount + 1;
       }
    }
    printf("%d integers\n", icount);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From the comments above, I believe this might be what you are looking for

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void)
{
    int  icount;
    int  index;
    char string[256];

    printf("Enter a string:\n\n");

    icount = 0;
    while (scanf("%255s", string) == 1)
    {
       int isNumber;

       isNumber = 1;
       for (index = 0 ; ((string[index] != '\0') && (isNumber != 0)) ; ++index)
       {
          printf("index is on its string[%d] iteration\n", index);
          if (isdigit(string[index]) == 0)
            isNumber = 0;
       }
       if (isNumber != 0)
          icount += 1;
    }
    printf("\nicount is %d\n", icount);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: looks like it would certainly work.  I went with something pretty simple though as my knowledge level with C at this point is well.. simple...